# Hostname is not localhost after installing MarkLogic in CentOS container

Tags: marklogic

I have written a dockerfile to install MarkLogic application in a CentOS machine.

After successfully installing the MarkLogic, I am able to open the admin at this url : http://localhost:8001.
But I see that the hostname is set as 866fab249ad3 in the admin console. Why is that so? As per my understanding, I thought that the hostname would be localhost.

Comment: What is returned if you execute `xdmp:hostname()`?

Comment: It returns 7504d7451067 in the query console. Also, I see that the hostname is set to 7504d7451067 in the admin console.

Comment: @MadsHansen : Any idea why my hostname is set as set of alphanumeric numbers instead of localhost. I tried to execute mlcp import command using this above hostname, for that it returns the same error like:  WARN mapreduce.MarkLogicOutputFormat: Unable to connect to 7504d7451067 to query destination information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Docker sets the hostname to be the Container ID, you can override it using the `--hostname` option.

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#ip-address-and-hostname

Comment: Thanks, I could change the hostname to localhost by passing it as an argument in docker run.